# Difference between Bhattacharyya distance and KL divergence

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, probability-distributions, means

Hello I am new to statistics therefore i would like to ask the following question. I recently encountered the terms Bhattacharyya distance and KL divergence. I also found out that the two   measures are based on variance and mean and also they are related to each other through inequality. My question is: If they are similar is there any application when one is better than the other? In what do they difer?

Thanks for the answers.